# How to change style of an element on another page using JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, styles

Ok, this is my problem... I have two pages. On the first page I have a header (`h2`) element on which I want to apply a border style. On the second page, there is only one link. When clicking on the link from the second page, to navigate to the first page, it should create a border on the first page around the `h2` tag.

Any thoughts on how to do this? Is it possible to do it with regular JavaScript or jQuery?

Thanks!

Comment: You are looking/viewing page 1 & 2 at the same time?

Comment: No, only one page is opened.

Comment: @VladimirSavić: Then you cannot do this purely client-side. You have to send a message to the server to tell it to update the other page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, JavaScript is client-side and for this you would require the server to remember if the link was clicked, possibly by recording this in a database or session variable.

That's of course if you're using the tradition model of a website, rather than loading pages already using pure JS.

Comment: OK, I'm looking for using PHP, but how I can then, know who clicked the link? Should I use his IP address or something else?

What the best option?

Comment: It really depends on the purpose of the site, and what you're using it for. Generally setting a session variable will work. Check out http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php for an intro to session variables.

Comment: No worries, may I suggest you accept the answers to this and your previous questions to encourage users to answer future questions.

Answer (score 1):

It would be a pretty stupid way of doing it, but it *is* possible to do it client side. I would seriously recommend to do it server-side though.

On page 2, link back to page 1 with a hash:

```
<a href="/page1#border">Go back to page one and add a border</a>
```

And on page 1, check if there's a hash:

```
if (window.location.hash === '#border') {
    $('h2').addClass('withBorder');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think if you are looking this kind of scenario you can achieve it with passing some hash to the url:

i `passed a hash named 'second'` in the `second page url` and put this script on second page

```
$(function(){
    var url=window.location;
    var hash = url.hash.substr(1);
    if(hash == "second"){
       $('h2').css('border','solid 1px red');
    }
});
```

Checkout this if helps.

Answer (score 0):

Well there is a way you could do this with JavaScript, although it's tricky and server side is a LOT easier.  You would need to use some JavaScript to load different pages without refreshing the entire DOM.  I do this with something called [pjax](http://pjax.heroku.com/).  The way it works is to have each page act as a container to load all subsequent pages via ajax.  By not doing a full page reload, any style changes you make on one page get carried over to other pages (this dose not survive an actual browser refresh).